# Syntax error on print with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do I receive a syntax error when printing a string in Python 3?

```
>>> print "hello World"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "hello World"
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: hint: for compatibility code in python 2.7+ put this into the beginning of the module: `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: ...import print_function doesn't seem to work, do you need to change something in the print statements? or should the import do it?

Comment: For the record, this case will be getting a custom error message in Python 3.4.2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python/

Comment: 2to3 is a Python program that reads Python 2.x source code and applies a series of fixers to transform it into valid Python 3.x code Further informations can be found here: [Python Documentation: Automated Python 2 to 3 code translation ](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)

Comment: Closing this as a dupe of the other post by @ncoghlan, because 1. It has a more comprehensive answer 2. It is updated to match the latest error.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

In Python 3, `print` [became a function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function). This means that you need to include parenthesis now like mentioned below:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 49):

It looks like you're using Python 3.0, in which [print has turned into a callable function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) rather than a statement.

```
print('Hello world!')
```

Answer (score 30):

Because in Python 3, `print statement` has been replaced with a `print() function`, with keyword arguments to replace most of the special syntax of the old print statement. So you have to write it as

```
print("Hello World")
```

But if you write this in a program and someone using Python 2.x tries to run it, they will get an error. To avoid this, it is a good practice to import print function:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Now your code works on both 2.x & 3.x.

Check out below examples also to get familiar with print() function.

```
Old: print "The answer is", 2*2
New: print("The answer is", 2*2)

Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline
New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline

Old: print              # Prints a newline
New: print()            # You must call the function!

Old: print >>sys.stderr, "fatal error"
New: print("fatal error", file=sys.stderr)

Old: print (x, y)       # prints repr((x, y))
New: print((x, y))      # Not the same as print(x, y)!
```

Source: [What’s New In Python 3.0?](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)