# print syntax error with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

After installing python 3.1, I cannot print anything. Here is an example:

```
>>> print "Hello World"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Hello World"
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: See [
python syntax error on print
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/python-syntax-error-on-print).

Comment: Install Python 2.7 (or read the documentation)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> print "Hello World!"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Hello World!"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print("Hello World!")
Hello World!
```

Python 3.X changed how print works, and now requires parentheses around the arguments.
Check out the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) for more.

Comment: Of course the alternative is to install python 2.x - there are many more tutorials out there for the 2.x releases.

Comment: The real alternative was *NOT* break basic functionality.

Answer (score 4):

if something's going wrong, you can always try to call for help:

```
>>> help(print)
Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
```

and there you might see, tha the syntax of that `print` thing is `print(something)`

funny is, that in python 2, you get just an error message:

```
>>> help(print)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

it's because in python < 3, `print` function was not a function, but a keyword (just like e.g. `for` or `or`)

Comment: In either version, you can do `help('print')`, though.

Answer (score 3):

This threw me off too!

```
print("Hello World")
```

The changes were documented here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are learning Python from a textbook that is telling you to type `print "Hello World"`, I recommend installing the Python version mentioned in the textbook.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah strange as it may seem i spent an hour trying to figure it out . At first could not believe how dumb i was to not even get the syntax right . This seems a consolation that python has changed .

```
print ("Hello World")
```

seems the way to go from now !