# invalid syntax error, what do i do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python. Can't seem to get this to work...

```
print = 'Press "U" and "Enter" for upper case.'
print = 'Press "L" and "Enter" for lower case.'
print = 'Press "C" and "Enter" for Capitalisation.'

letter = input("Please type a letter and press enter: ")
if letter == u: print '"THE MOST PROFOUND TECHNOLOGIES ARE THOSE THAT DISAPPEAR: THEY     WEAVE THEMSELVES INTO FABRIC OF EVERYDAY LIFE UNTIL ARE INDISTINGUISHABLE FROM IT" [MARK     WEISER, THE COMPUTER FOR THE 21ST CENTURY, SCIENTIFIC AMERICAN, SEPT. 1991]'
if letter == l: print '"the most profound technologies are those that disappear: they     weave themselves into fabric of everyday life until are indistinguishable from it" [mark weiser, the computer for the 21st century, scientific american, sept. 1991]'
if letter == c: print '"The most profound technologies are those that disappear: they weave themselves into fabric of everyday life until are indistinguishable from it" [Mark Weiser, The Computer for the 21st Century, Scientific American, Sept. 1991]'
```

also how can I improve the program so that the user can replace a one word
with another word.

Comment: Use `print` as a function in py3.x and don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: `print =???` That's the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error on print with Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3)

Comment: When you say new to python, which document or tutorial are you reading? Or are you going by "trial and error" learning?

Comment: You probably also want to have a look at `string.lower()` and `string.upper()`...

Comment: trail and error since the tutorial the school gave me was before 2.6 and the download link was for 3.3.2...

Comment: @user2750488 http://python.org/download/releases/

Comment: too far through the work to turn back now...

Comment: When you get a syntax error, it prints the line number of the error.  That will usually help you in debugging your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
formats = {"U": {"text": "upper case", "func": str.upper},
           "L": {"text": "lower case", "func": str.lower},
           "C": {"text": "Capitalization", "func": lambda x: x}
          }

data = '"The most profound technologies are those that disappear: they weave themselves into fabric of everyday life until are indistinguishable from it" [Mark Weiser, The Computer for the 21st Century, Scientific American, Sept. 1991]'

for c in formats:
    print('Press "{}" and "Enter" for {}.'.format(c, formats[c]['text']))

letter = input("Please type a letter and press enter: ")
if letter in formats:
    print(formats[letter]['func'](data))
```

Comment: will this work for 3.3.2>

Comment: @user2750488 it should

Answer (score 0):

Should say

```
print('Press "U" and "Enter" for upper case.')
print('Press "L" and "Enter" for lower case.')
print('Press "C" and "Enter" for Capitalisation.')
```

I'd recommend using pythons string.replace function for replacing strings :)

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: This is the second time i have made this mistake... thanks alot.

Comment: Mark as selected if it fixed it ;)

Comment: still have another error but you fixed the invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Press "U" and "Enter" for upper case.')
```

Answer (score 0):

also you should probably be using a function like upper() on your user input to account for both lower and upper case values:

```
if letter.upper() == U ........
```

Comment: how where would i use this?

Comment: on the next couple lines after this:    `letter = input("Please type a letter and press enter: ")`  It will take the value of whatever they press, and convert it to upper case, so it will be consistent no matter if they type in lower case or upper case at the prompt.  Note that you should then of course, be checking against upper case values for the letters.