# Unable to see error in simple python code

Tags: python

I am trying the code in the tutorial given here - 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Python/article.html

He uses python 2.6 and I use 3.3. I don't know if that causes my problem.

My code -

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b 

def addFixedValue(a):
    y = 5
    return y+a

print add(1,2)
print addFixedValue(1)
```

Error is -

```
    print add(1,2)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I correct it ?

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3.

Comment: in python 3, I'm pretty sure print x becomes print(x)

http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: Why am I getting a -1 for this ? If I was already knew py programming, I would not be asking my first py question.

Comment: Why would someone down-vote this question?  It is well written, clear, provides complete source code, references, operating environment (Python version) specific error message and specific question!  Seems to me it's ideal! (???)

Comment: @aldo because of the number of results for searching "python 3 print SyntaxError" here and elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python versions before 3, `print` was a statement, not a function, so the code as you have it here is correct.

Starting with Python 3, `print` is now a function, so you need to wrap arguments in parentheses.

#### Python 1.x - 2.x:

```
print "This is a string"
```

#### Python 3.x:

```
print("This is a string")
```

The rationale behind this change is explained at http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/

Comment: Yes, I was also confused as to why there would be such a syntax change. I have never seen this in C, C++, C#, Java, SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `print` is a function and thus requires parentheses:

```
print(add(1,2))
print(addFixedValue(1))
```

For more information, see [Print is a Function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function).

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.6, the following would work:

```
>>> print 'hi'
hi
```

However, `print` is a function in python 3.3, so surround it with parentheses:

```
>>> print(add(1,1))
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3/826957#826957) for more information, and [**here**](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) for the syntaxing from the docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python 3.3, `print` is no longer a statement, but a function. You thus need to put brackets around the printed object.

```
print(add(1,2))
print(addFixedValue(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, print is a function

```
print(add(1,2))
print(addFixedValue(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try 2to3 for converting python 2.x program to python 3.x Documentation @ [Automated Python 2 to 3 code translation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)