# python print invalid syntax

Tags: python, string

`print (n+1) ": x1= ",x1,"f(x)= ",fx`

I want it to print what the x1 is and the value of the function at x1 (fx), but I get an invalid syntax on the end of the first quotation. Can someone explain to me what my problem is.

Comment: If you are using Python 3, probably look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are

1. There should be a comma(,) before the 1st quotation.

   print (n+1), " : x1=",x1,"f(x)=",fx
2. printing f(x) will print correct value if you have a return statement in the function

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do ( Assuming all are integers):

```
print("%d: x1= %d f(x)=%d" % ((n+1),x1,fx))
```

Comment: what if function produces floats?

Comment: feel free to use any format specifiers you want from https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language   if the type is only determined at run time you can use crclayton answer

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma after n+1

```
print (n+1), " : x1=",x1,"f(x)=",fx
```