# syntax error when use except keyword

Tags: python

I am new to Python app development. I know about the Python exceptions, but when I use the `except` keyword it shows me `SyntaxError`. My code is

```
number = 1
try:
if(number == 1):
except ValueError:
print "yay"
else:

print "sucks"
```

When I use this code it gives me a syntax error when I add the `except` keyword. Since I'm new to Python I don't know why it's happening like this. I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: There is no block after `if`. Not that your indentation is at all correct here, but what you are trying to do is entirely impossible.

Comment: It is not clear even what you are trying to do. What would throw a `ValueError` here?

Comment: Indent your code correctly

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have tried another ways too but when i type excpet it shows syntax error ..:/

Answer (score 6):

```
number = 1
try:
    if(number == 1):
        print 'yay'
    else: 
        print 'sucks'
except ValueError:
    print 'Oops, something went wrong'
```

Follow this structure and you will be golden pony boy.

Comment: ..when i type except on python gui ..it shows me syntax error.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I just ran this code and it worked fine. Could you take a screenshot?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/klnqlswtl/ see this ..when i type 'yay' it shows me syntax error..

Comment: @user3760836: You are using Python 3; [`print()` is a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3).

Comment: oops ..but when i call except it throws the same error ...is there any special  way of calling exception in python 3.4 ??

Comment: print('yay') you call it like that.

Comment: Are you typing try first? Or just except? Except without try is a syntax error

Answer (score 5):

You cannot mix up Python statements like that.

`try ... except` is *one* compound statement; each of the two blocks contained (for the `try` and the `except`) need to be fully independent statements of their own. `if ... else ...` is *also* a compound statement, so it has to be *entirely* within either the `try` or the `except` block, or entirely outside of it.

This would work:

```
number = 1
try:
    if number == 1:
        print("yay")
    else:
        print("sucks")
except ValueError:
    pass
```

because now the whole of `if .. else` is inside the `try` block.

Not that you *need* to handle `ValueError` here, there is nothing in the code block that would throw the exception.

From the comments it is clear you are using Python 3 (and IDLE), so you want to use `print()` as a function.

Comment: when i type except on python gui ..it  still shows me syntax error

Comment: @user3760836: Then either you are doing something wrong, or your Python GUI is showing an error where there is none. Without seeing your exact GUI contents, that is impossible to tell, and way beyond the scope of what we can help you with.

Comment: @user3760836: looks like you are seeing this: [Syntax error on print with Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/826948)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.0 , print became a function, you need to include parenthesis as you must for other functions. So
`print var` becomes `print(var)`

Since you're using Python3 try the following:

```
number = 1
try:
    if (number == 1):
         print ("yay")
    else:
        print ("other opts")
except ValueError:
     print ("Something went wrong")
```

Comment: can you take a screenshot? Also can you ensure that indents are specified properly.