# Correct syntax for python print statement

Tags: python, python-2.x

I don't have much knowledge of python. I have a code written in python which I am trying to compile. Its giving me following error

```
 File "parseBvh.py", line 382
    print(T[0],T[1],T[2],file=fp)
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried to find out the correct syntax but am not able to. Can someone point me in right direction?

Comment: No need to assign anything: `print(T[0],T[1],T[2],fp)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error on print with Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, [`print` is a statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt), not a function:

```
print >> fp, T[0],T[1],T[2]
```

or (probably better):

```
fp.write(" ".join(T[:3]) + "\n") # [:3] may be dropped if T only has 3 items
```