# python w/ pandas invalid syntax

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.4 using Pandas in beginners tutorial. Code below. Keep getting syntax error in print with carrot under the d in pd.  Spent last hour trolling the web to no avail. Just starting out.

```
import numpy as np
import csv as csv
import pandas as pd
readdata = csv.reader(open("c:\MyData\BYLCsv.csv"))
data = []

for row in readdata:
    data.append(row)

Header = data[0]
data.pop(0)
print pd.DataFrame(data, columns=Header)
```

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3

Comment: I find it helps to google for keywords.  For example, "python print syntax error".

Comment: basically python 3 print is a function so you have to wrap your args in parentheses so  do this `print(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=Header))`

Comment: And apart from the print error, you can also use `pd.read_csv` instead of looping over the csv file rows yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using python 3 and for the print command you need the parenthesis:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(data, columns=Header))
```