# Unable to print the result

Tags: python, function

I've been going through Codecademy's Python course and I'm currently stuck on 6/19 of the functions chapter. I managed to write the code according to the instructions but I decided to tinker with it a little. This was the initial code I wrote:

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3
def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return False
```

However, I wanted it to print out the result according to the number I would input in the parentheses below. So this is what I wrote:

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3
def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number)
        print cube(number)
    else:
        return False
        print "False"
cube(5)
```

I didn't get any errors, but I didn't get the print I wanted either. However, when I put the code in a different Python editor, I got a syntax error on line 6.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The syntax error is almost certainly caused by you using Python 3. See [Syntax error on print with Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/826948) and [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25445439)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `print` statements never get executed for two reasons:

- They follow *after* the `return` statements. `return` exits a function *at that point*, and any further statements in the function body are ignored as they are never reached.
- You call the `cube()` function, not the `by_three()` function.

Move your `print` statements *before* the `return` lines, and call he correct function:

```
def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        print cube(number)
        return cube(number)
    else:
        print "False"
        return False

by_three(5)
```

You can replace the `print` lines with `print()` function calls to make the code work in a Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks a bunch!