# Why is print("{}").format() valid syntax?

Tags: python

Ran into some interesting Python behavior today. I though I was writing

```
print("{}".format("some value"))
```

but instead I wrote

```
print("{}").format("some value")
```

and funnily enough it worked. So my question is, how does this work?

## Digging deeper

This behavior seems to be python2 specific.

### Python2.7

```
>>> print("{}").format("testing")
testing
```

### Python3.4

```
>>> print("{}").format("testing)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("{}").format("testing)
                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

It also seems like the print function of python2 doesn't have a return value but Python3 does? so that confuses me even more.

### Python2.7

```
>>> type(print("testing))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    type(print("testing))
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a = print("testing")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = print("testing")
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

### Python3.4

```
>>> type(print("{}"))
{}
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> a = print("{}")
{}
>>> a
>>> type(a)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: As a side note (unrelated to the parentheses issue), you probably shouldn't be doing `"{}".format(something)`. This is usually going to be identical to `str(something)`, and even that is unnecessary if you're passing the result to `print`, (which will call `str` on its arguments for you).

Comment: You're missing some fundamental information about `print` (check the suggested [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3?rq=1) in the sidebar), and some of your strings aren't terminated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error on print with Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3)

Comment: There are multiple things being tried here, that are not really related, each with a separate explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, not a function (unless you do `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your module). This means that the parentheses around the thing you're printing are not part of a function call, but just treated as grouping parentheses. In the situation you describe `("{}")` is the same as `"{}"` (the parens do nothing), so the `format` call works just like you'd expect if you wrote `"{}".format(...)`.

In Python 3, `print` is a function, so the parentheses are not optional and can't be put in the wrong place. `print` returns `None`, so you're almost certainly going to get an error if you do `print(something).something_else`, since `None` doesn't have a `something_else` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7, `print` is a statement; this means that

```
print("{}").format("testing")
```

prints one expression, the result of the expression `("{}").format("testing")`. That is, the `format` method is called on the (parenthesized) string before the print statement is evaluated. If you use

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

in the 2.7 examples, you'll get identical behavior to Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're missing the closing quote after some strings (e.g. `"testing`).
2. As others are saying, Python 2 doesn't have a `print()` function, it has a `print` statement. Your strings (even if they were properly closed) are not what and where you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, [`print` is a statement keyword](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) like `raise`, not a function.  Parentheses aren't used for its arguments, and so `print("{}").format("testing")` is parsed as though you'd written `print ("{}").format("testing")`, which is the same as `print(("{}").format("testing"))`.  Because `print` is a statement, it cannot be used as an expression, and therefore it cannot have a return value.

If you want `print` in Python 2 to act like Python 3's `print` function, place this line at the top of your file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `yield` is now an expression, not a statement in recent versions of Python 3 (you can do `foo = yield bar`).

Comment: @Blckknght: `foo = yield bar` also works in Python 2. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr

Comment: @PM2Ring: Ah, I'd forgotten when that feature was added.