# Python: invalid syntax about bs4

Tags: python, urllib2, beautifulsoup

**my code is**

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = urllib2.urlopen('https://poloniex.com/exchange#btc_xrp').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res)

print soup.find("a")
```

**result is**

```
File "python_bitcoin_alart.py", line 7
print soup.find("a")
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know why I have this error.....

Comment: Do you use Python3  ? Then you need print with `()` - `print(soup.find("a"))`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3 (now seven and a half years old...)

Comment: You also have the problem that the code is written for python2