# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format' in python3.4

Tags: python

```
predictions = getPredictions(summaries, testSet)
accuracy = getAccuracy(testSet, predictions)
print('Accuracy: {0}%').format(accuracy)
```

There is an error in the above code:

```
print('Accuracy: {0}%').format(accuracy)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: `print('Accuracy: {0}%'.format(accuracy))`

Comment: Please see the duplicates or use google first before submitting a new question. When posting a question here, SO lists possible duplicates; and it doesn't allow even you to post the question without `in python3.4` because that title already exists.

Answer (score -1):

Should be

```
print('Accuracy: {0}%'.format(accuracy))
```

Answer (score -1):

try applying format to 'Accuracy: {0}%' and then print it

Answer (score -1):

In python 3.4, print function needs **()** to print any statement. This function print output to stdout console and return **None**. Here you are applying format to **return** value of **print** function. Hence it throws **NoneTypeError**.

So use format on string, instead return value of print:-

```
print('Accuracy: {0}%'.format(accuracy))
```

Comment: it is not only in Python 3.4, it is in Python 3 that `print` becomes a function instead of a keyword.

Comment: You can get more information about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3/)

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf yes in python 3 it uses (), but check question carefully it is asked about python 3.4