# Invalid Syntax Error On Python3 About print

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

```
def Corner(n):
  if n == 3:
    print('İts An Triangle \nBu Bir Üçgen')
  elif n == 4:
    print('İts An Rectangle or Square or Parrallelogram \nBu Bir 
   Dikdörtgen yada Kare yada ParalelKenar ')
  elif n == 5:
    print('İts An Pentagon \nBu Bir Beşgen')
  elif n == 6:
    print('İts An Hexagon \nBu Bir Altıgen')
  else:
    print('Bir Köşe Sayısı Girmediniz \nYou Didnt Wrote a Corner 
 Number '

print Corner(6)

**File "Köşegen.py", line 13
print Corner(6)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

Its The Error Code I wrote it on Python3
This Code About the Corners and Shapes but I had that massage when I run the code

Comment: Close your parentheses, and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Comment: @MrT That in itself is a duplicate of above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some parentheses:

```
print('Bir Köşe Sayısı Girmediniz \nYou Didnt Wrote a Corner Number ') # here

print(Corner(6)) # and here
```

Comment: Thanks For Help Its Worked

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, print is a function just like any other, so you need parentheses, as below:

```
print(' something ')
```

Rather than:

```
print ' something '
```

In python 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm Closed The Parantheses and Its Worked Thanks For Help Artemis Fowl and Todd W

```
def Corner(n):
  if n == 3:
    print('İts An Triangle \nBu Bir Üçgen')
  elif n == 4:
    print('İts An Rectangle or Square or Parrallelogram \nBu Bir 
   Dikdörtgen yada Kare yada ParalelKenar')
  elif n == 5:
    print('İts An Pentagon \nBu Bir Beşgen')
  elif n == 6:
    print('İts An Hexagon \nBu Bir Altıgen')
  else:
   print('Bir Köşe Sayısı Girmediniz \nYou Didnt Wrote a Corner Number')

print(Corner(6))
```