# minimum/max function (without built in functions!)

Tags: python

I am trying to find the max and min of a list of random numbers without using any built in functions. I have this code, but its showing an invalid syntax error on the last line. Can someone help? Using spyder in python 3.7. Also I know that the random number list works, just the min code is not working.

```
import random

l = []

for i in range(0,50):
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    l.append(x)

print(l)

def minimum(list):
  current_min = list[0]  
  for num in list:       
    if num < current_min:
      current_min = num  
  return current_min

print minimum(l)
```

Comment: What error? Please provide as much information as you can. Is this Python 3? Did you do any research before posting?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should include the exact error message in the question. It cuts down on the ambiguity. I can tell what you meant, but you're still getting questions about it, for good reason.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/49638320/1766544

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using python 3, then I expect the last line is returning an error because you are missing the brackets on the print statement, it should be

```py
print (minimum(l))
```

On another note, you can also shorten the initialization of your list into a one-liner

```py
l = [random.randint(1, 10) for x in range(50)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In python3, you should use print with parenthesis.
Change your last line to be `print(minimum(l))`