# Python syntax error with "

Tags: python

Hello I'm  a noob and just started using python so I wanted to have fun using `raw_input` , adding random questions and stuff but I came across an error. It says the invalid syntax is ". I've been trying to put it to different places but didnt succeed I'm sorry if this is a really dumb question but can someone help me out.

**Heres a line with the error**

```
print " Oh okay then %s . You came from %s , right? Oh i see you came here to %s" % (name,so,fun)
```

It's pointing at the closing " next to `%s`

I'm using `atom`

edit: heres the error

```
 File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.26.1\Testing.py", line 10
print " Oh okay then %s . You came from %s , right? Oh i see you came here %s. " % (name, so, fun)
                                                                               ^
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**Heres the full code :**

```
name = raw_input("Hello whats your name?")
so = raw_input("From where did you come from")
fun = raw_input("Interesting, why did you come here?")
#start the sentence with "for"


print " Oh okay then %s . You came from %s , right? Oh i see you came here %s. " % (name, so, fun)
```

If I can't use `raw_input` what can I use then? I learned with using that.

Comment: Look at str.format() instead.

Comment: There's no syntax error in that line of code. Please post a [mcve] - enough code to reproduce the problem, and the complete traceback.

Comment: You didn't show us how you defined `name`, `so` , or `fun`, but I guess you're trying to run that code on Python 3. That code's valid on Python 2, but not Python 3. OTOH, `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3, so your question is a little puzzling.

Comment: @PM2Ring you're correct, it can be posted as answer instead of comment

Comment: @AndriyMaletsky Well, I don't know if this question really needs a full answer. And I'd like to resolve the `raw_input` mystery before I commit myself to writing a proper answer.

Comment: Oh im sorry ill edit my question right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error on print with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by putting brackets around the whole thing like

```
print (" Oh okay then %s . You came from %s , right? Oh i see you came here to %s" % (name,so,fun))
```

Also I believe that raw_input was replaced with 'input()'.

Comment: Why is this downvoted, I have no issue removing it just want to know for future reference

Comment: Thank you it worked !! Im sorry for this dumb question ill try harder to fix my own problem.

Comment: why did you put quotes around "so" and "fun"? Those are clearly defined as variables in the question and making them string literals changes the behavior