# Whatever I do, I get syntax error on print. Here is the code below, i can't find what is wrong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# QUESTION 5; Only looking at the three most populous counties for each state, what are the three
# most populous states (in order of highest population to lowest population)?
# Use `CENSUS2010POP

census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
census_df.head()

def question7():
    return "hllo"

def question8():

    c = census_df
    c = c[(c['REGION'] == 1) | (c['REGION'] == 2)] # region 1 or 2
    c = c.where(c['CTYNAME'].str.startswith('Washington')).dropna() # Washington name
    c = c[c['POPESTIMATE2015'] > c['POPESTIMATE2014']] #POP 15 > POP 14
    c = c.sort_index(ascending=True)
    print c[['STNAME', 'CTYNAME']


print (question7())
```

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you need parenthesis around whatever you are printing.  It is no longer a statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python)

Comment: Anther Possible duplicate: [Syntax error on print with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3)

Comment: print(question7()) should work in Python 3 then... this should be a different issue.. ?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
    print c[['STNAME', 'CTYNAME']
```

is missing parentheses for the print function call. Change it to,

```
    print(c[['STNAME', 'CTYNAME'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for three most pop counties :

```
def answer_six():
  largest = census_df.nlargest(3, ['CENSUS2010POP']) 
  return largest[['STNAME', 'CTYNAME', 'CENSUS2010POP']]
```